# How might I install fglrx 9.0.2 on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, fglrx

The fglrx-updates package in 13.04 contains fglrx 9.1.11. For some reason, this driver is not nearly as good for certain OpenCL work as the 9.0.2 driver found in fglrx-updates for Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10.

How might I go about installing fglrx 9.0.2 on Ubuntu 13.04?

Any reason why I can not or should not?

I could certainly go back to 12.04 LTS, but it would be nice to stay on 13.04.

Comment: you can search for the package you want from here:
http://packages.ubuntu.com
search for it in lucid or precise , download it and install it manually.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would purge the current driver and alter my sources.list to use quantal
`sudo sed -i 's/raring/quantal/' /etc/apt/sources.list;sudo apt-get update`
then install the driver you want and what ever other quantal stuff you want
then switch back to raring
`sudo sed -i 's/quantal/raring/' /etc/apt/sources.list;sudo apt-get update`
then lock the driver in synaptic
then lock it in dpkg
`echo $MY_PACKAGE_NAME_HERE hold | dpkg --set-selections`
I think this would easier than downloading the debs and then hunting down all of the dependencies
You may have to downgrade Xorg to install older AMD drivers and have them work

Comment: The fglrx-updates package from quantel appears not be compatible out of the box, and the driver is not loaded into kernel. I'm sure this can be worked around, but I'll just go back to 12.04 for now. Thanks anyway!